# What if a robot breaks in the process of reinforcement learning

Tags: deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

Let's say I try to make a jumping robot with RL. But RL requires trial and error, and of course, my robot will fail in jumping a lot of times at the beginning.

How do developers teach a robot that could break while learning?

Comment: Same way you keep acrobats safe while they learn new routines: nets and cables.

Answer (score 1):

> What if a robot breaks in the process of reinforcement learning?

Then you have a broken robot.

> How do people teach a robot that could break while learning with RL?

I would do it like this:

1. Make a simulation. There are physical simulations out there, so first make sure your RL agent acts reasonably there.
2. Have constraints: Maybe you don't want to let it jump directly. Let's first try to make it stand.
3. Loosening constraints. Once one task is solved, go for a more complex one / one with higher probability that hardware is damaged.

And, of course, add cables to the robot that catches it if it falls. I remember seeing that for robots from Boston Dynamics, but I can't find the videos right now.